# OAUTH2: On accessing the REST end point from customer end UI to secure URI returns anonymousUser

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, oauth-2.0, spring-data-jpa, spring-rest

I am working on OAUTH2 spring security, i am supposed to hit http://localhost:8082/ui - REST end point from client UI which will take me to the secure URI http://localhost:8082/secure after logging into the auth server http://localhost:8081/auth/login.

But instead it after hitting on client UI http://localhost:8082/ui it is directly taking me to http://localhost:8082/secure, not prompting for login page. and on secure page "anonymousUser" value is returned.

I am sharing my client and server below, and value returned is "Welcome Login User!== anonymousUser".
Any help would be really appreciated where i'm doing wrong.

my client side configuration

```
@EnableOAuth2Sso
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class OauthConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

     @Autowired
        private OAuth2ClientContextFilter oauth2ClientContextFilter;



    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

    http
        .authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/**")    
       .permitAll()

       .antMatchers("/", "/login/**")     
       .permitAll()
            .anyRequest()
            .authenticated().and()
            .httpBasic().and().addFilterAfter(oauth2ClientContextFilter, SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.class);
        }

    @Bean
    protected OAuth2RestTemplate OAuth2RestTemplate(
        OAuth2ProtectedResourceDetails resource, OAuth2ClientContext context) {
      return new OAuth2RestTemplate(resource, context);
    }
    }
```

application.yml

```
server:
  port: 8082
  servlet:
    context-path: /ui
  session: 
    cookieName: UISESSION

 security:
   oauth2: 
    client: 
      clientId: ClientId
      clientSecret: secret
      accessTokenUri: http://localhost:8081/auth/oauth/token
      userAuthorizationUri: http://localhost:8081/auth/oauth/authorize
      scope: openid
    resource: 
      userInfoUri: http://localhost:8081/auth/rest/hello/principal
      preferTokenInfo: false
```

application.properties

```
spring.thymeleaf.cache= false
spring.mvc.view.prefix=/
spring.mvc.view.suffix=.html

spring.autoconfigure.exclude=org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.SecurityAutoConfiguration

server.port= 8082
server.servlet.session.cookie.name=UISESSION

spring.thymeleaf.mode=LEGACYHTML5


management.endpoints.web.expose=*
```

server side authorization server

```
@Configuration
@EnableAuthorizationServer
public class AuthorisationServerConfig extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;



    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerSecurityConfigurer security) throws Exception {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        //security.allowFormAuthenticationForClients();
        security.tokenKeyAccess("permitAll()")
        .checkTokenAccess("isAuthenticated()");

    }

    @Override
    public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {

        clients.inMemory().withClient("ClientId")//.authorities("ROLE_ADMIN")
        .secret("{noop}secret")
        .authorizedGrantTypes("authorization_code").scopes("user_info").autoApprove(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) throws Exception {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        endpoints.authenticationManager(authenticationManager);
    }

}
```

serve side resource server

```
@EnableResourceServer
@Configuration
@Order(1000)    
public class ResourceServerConfig  extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager; 
    @Autowired

    private  UserDetailsService customUserDetailsService;

    @Autowired
      public ResourceServerConfig(AuthenticationManager authenticationManager, 
              CustomUserDetailsService customUserDetailsService) {
        this.authenticationManager = authenticationManager;
        this.customUserDetailsService = customUserDetailsService;
      }


    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http.requestMatchers().antMatchers("/login","/oauth/authorize").and().authorizeRequests()
        .anyRequest().authenticated().and().formLogin().permitAll();


    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {


        auth.parentAuthenticationManager(authenticationManager).
        userDetailsService(customUserDetailsService);

    }
}
```

server side Service

```
@Service
public class CustomUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService{

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Optional<Users> userOptional= userRepository.findByName(username);
        userOptional.orElseThrow(() -> new UsernameNotFoundException("user not found"));
        return userOptional.map(users -> new CustomUserDetails(users)).get();
    }


}
```

Comment: Whatever you put below `.antMatchers("/**").permitAll()` has no effect at all... always put special cases first, general cases last. Why did you even include this configuration? It's in direct opposition to `.anyRequest().authenticated()`

Comment: @crizzis as suggested i changed the matchers to http.antMatcher("/**")
        .authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/", "/login**")
        .permitAll()
        .anyRequest()
        .authenticated()   ........................but now my older issue "Full authentication is required to access this resource" is coming...i provided every right but this error persists.

Comment: Just to be clear, your config should now look as follows: `http().authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/", "/login/**").permitAll().anyRequest().authenticated()` - is that the case?

Comment: Also, is the 'old issue' of getting 'Full authentication is required to access this resource' message coming from the app server of the auth server?

Comment: @crizzis yes, Full authentication is required to access this resource is coming from auth server, and this is how my client side config is look like .. `http.antMatcher("/**")
        .authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/", "/login**")
        .permitAll()
        .anyRequest()
        .authenticated()`